# Arrows to points inside the axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am making an image that shows plotting points on the cartesian plane. I am using the `axis` environment from `pgfplots`. It works well for plotting the points but I can not seem to figure out where to place the arrows to show the movement. I could try to calculate the location but it seems like there should be a better method.

The working part is:

```
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}     %for graphics
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}     %to run newest version
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark,arrows,arrows.meta,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-5, xmax=5, ymin=-5, ymax=5, 
axis lines=middle, myaxis, xtick = {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}, ytick = {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4},
xlabel = \(x\), ylabel = \(y\)]
    \addplot+[only marks] coordinates {(0,1) (-2,4) (1,-3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-5, xmax=5, ymin=-5, ymax=5, 
axis lines=middle, myaxis, xtick = {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4}, ytick = {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4},
xlabel = \(x\), ylabel = \(y\)]

    \addplot+[only marks] coordinates {(0,1) (-2,4) (1,-3)};
\end{axis}

\draw[green,-latex, very thick] (0,0) -- (0,1);
\draw[blue,latex-, very thick] (0,0) -- (-2,0);
\draw[blue,-latex, very thick] (-2,0) -- (-2,4);
\draw[gray,-latex, very thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[gray,-latex, very thick] (1,0) -- (1,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But this failed quite spectacularly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `axis` coordinate system to reference points in your diagrams. For this, the `\draw` operation need to be used inside the `axis` environment.

Now, you can use `(axis cs: <x>, <y>)` to reference point (*x*, *y*) in your diagram.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}     %for graphics
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}     %to run newest version
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=-5, xmax=5, ymin=-5, ymax=5,
  axis lines=middle,
  %myaxis, % don't know this
  xtick = {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4},
  ytick = {-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4},
  xlabel = \(x\),
  ylabel = \(y\)
]

\addplot+[only marks] coordinates {(0,1) (-2,4) (1,-3)};

\draw[green,-latex, very thick](axis cs: 0,0) -- (axis cs: 0, 1);
\draw[blue,latex-, very thick] (axis cs: 0,0) -- (axis cs:-2, 0);
\draw[blue,-latex, very thick] (axis cs:-2,0) -- (axis cs:-2, 4);
\draw[gray,-latex, very thick] (axis cs: 0,0) -- (axis cs: 1, 0);
\draw[gray,-latex, very thick] (axis cs: 1,0) -- (axis cs: 1,-3);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you very much. I realized that I included the myaxis which was a custom addition to make the arrows appear on both sides of the axis. That is what I needed though, so perfect.

Comment: As a quick follow up, any suggestions on how to make the coordinate points different colors (or just all black)? I seem to be able to encircle them, but can not seem to change the color.

Comment: @GregoryVarner Check section 3.3.2 of the `pgfplots` manual. Just use `\addplot[<options>]` (without the `+`) and just choose your styles for the plot. Here `<options>` would just be `black`. I don't know different colors. But you can just use multiple `\addplot` in one `axis` environment.

Comment: Yep. That did it. I figured that it was something simple. I was working off of an example I found online and could not seem to adjust it properly.